# Onclick-> refresh on image only not page

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any method can i use to refresh the image ONLY when i click on the image and count is increasing? I don't want the entire page to refresh because if refresh the page, the click counter will need to count from 0 again.

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$table1=mysql_query("select * from pic_a");
$table2=mysql_query("select * from pic_b");
$table3=mysql_query("select * from pic_c");

$tab1[0]=0;
$tab2[0]=0;
$tab3[0]=0;

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table1))
{
    $tab1[$i]= $row['pic_link']; 
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table2))
{
    $tab2[$i]= $row['pic_link']; 
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($table3))
{
    $tab3[$i]= $row['pic_link']; 
    $i++;
}

    $rand1=rand(0,9);
$rand2=rand(0,9);
$rand3=rand(0,9);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
         count = count + 1;
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
        }
```

```
<table  border="1">
          <tr id="bird" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab1[$rand1]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
            <td>Bird</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="car" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab2[$rand2]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
            <td>Car</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="computer" onclick="countClicks();">
            <td><img src="password\<?php echo $tab3[$rand3]; ?>" alt="" width="76" height="67"></td>
            <td>Computer</td>
          </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No `onclick` event for `<img>` .

You have to wrap it inside a `<a>`

you can call `onclick` function then and use a js variable to keep track of number of clicks

Answer (score 0):

You can always use AJAX for updating the counter on click of image. (if you want to save it in database)

jQuery AJAX is the simplest and quickest to start.

**ELSE**

Create one element on the page with id = "cnt"

```
function countClicks()
{
   document.getElementById("cnt").value = Number(document.getElementById("cnt").value) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i want to do some sort like that. For example, each picture will be assigned a "click" number in table, lets say picture "A" with 3 clicks. When the image is displayed, users will click the exact click(s) on the image. while clicking, it will keep refresh the image. 
What am i doing is actually a simple graphical count click authentication system. Is it possible to do so ?
Can you explain more on "You can always use AJAX for updating the counter on click of image. (if you want to save it in database)

jQuery AJAX is the simplest and quickest to start."

Thank you so much for the reply ^^

Comment: if you want to save counter for all images in database, use AJAX call which calls a php page with current image selection and updates database.

Comment: you can use $.ajax() function of jQuery

Comment: I doubt teaching libraries such as `jQuery` before the user has at least got to know the fundamentals of the language is not the best idea.